# Cocos2d sprite touch events in hi-res mode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite class that includes touch listeners for touching and dragging. This is all working fine.

But I recently added hi-res images for all my sprites and have enabled retina display support using this in the app delegate:

```
[director setContentScaleFactor:2];
```

The problem I'm having now is that when scale factor is doubled, my sprite class is no longer detecting touches. I have tried to use these solutions to no avail: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/10284

In my sprite class I have a rect method:

```
- (CGRect)rect
{
    CGSize s = [self.texture contentSizeInPixels];
    return CGRectMake(-s.width / 2, -s.height / 2, s.width, s.height);
}
```

Then in my containsTouchLocation method I have:

```
- (BOOL)containsTouchLocation:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.rect, [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:touch]);
}
```

When I return YES here manually everything works the way it should so it's clearly something to do with the CGRect points.

Any ideas? I'm using Cocos2d 0.99.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out (with the help of the the cocos2d community). If anyone else comes across this issue in the future, this is how you fix this problem.

In your project, find CCNode.m and all the way down the bottom, replace these two methods with this:

```
- (CGPoint)convertTouchToNodeSpace:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];
    return [self convertToNodeSpace:ccp( point.x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(), point.y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR())]; //point];
}

- (CGPoint)convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];
    return [self convertToNodeSpaceAR:ccp( point.x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(), point.y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR())];
}
```